# android : animating button on press through xml

Tags: android, animation

in an android app, am trying to animate a button. I referred this:
[In Android, Display pressed button animation in OnClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109227/in-android-display-pressed-button-animation-in-onclick)

This is the button image :

[image]

When touched, I want this to show a rotating animation. For this, I created the same in various rotation angles like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I created a custom button.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@anim/anim_refresh_button">    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh">    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh"></item>
</selector>
```

Then, for animation, I created anim_refresh_button.xml (which I have mentioned in 'state_pressed' above) as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="true">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh_1" android:duration="500"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh_2" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh_3" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_refresh_4" android:duration="500" />

 </animation-list>
```

When I press the button, it does animate a bit. meaning it goes to one image in the animation-list above and then returns to its state. I tried increasing the duration to 1000 suspecting that it's just fast that am not able to notice the animation. But, in vain. I want the arrow to rotate when pressed. And this rotation effect should be visible clearly to the user. can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(3000);
iv.setAnimation(anim);
iv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change this in your Animation List of (anim_refresh_button.xml):

```
android:oneshot="false"
```

Instead

```
android:oneshot="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

make global to this method and thread in your activity like this :-

```
private void Animation() {
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.anim_image);
            anim = (AnimationDrawable)img.getDrawable();
            img.post(run);
        }

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                anim.start();
             }
        };
```

Now just call

```
 Animation();
```

in oncreate() of activity

this is image view code in xml

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/anim_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cmnttext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@anim/animationofdownloading" />
```

and this is src animationofdownloading of image

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_first"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_sec"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_thi"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_four"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_fiv"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_six"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_sev"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_eig"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_nin"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_ten"
    android:duration="40"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cloud_ele"
    android:duration="40"/>
```

hope it will help you 
best of luck dude :)